# How can I sorting the values in the jumping columns?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrices 25x600 and some columns contains positive and negative values. I want the output like this [+ + - -] (four values 2 positive and 2 negative). I am guaranteed to always have two positive values immediately before the transition and two negative values immediately after. my attempting was as follow :

My attempt was as follows:

```
    clc;
    clear all;
    close all;
    %%
    data=[-0.0059972;-0.004994;-0.0029881;2.0868e-05;
0.0030299;0.013059;0.033115;0.063196;0.093273;0.1935;0.39385;0.69423;0.99448;1.9950;3.99550;6.99550;9.9957;19.9961;39.99620;69.9960;
99.99530;199.99810;399.99140;699.98860;1000.03130]
    for r=1:600
        lam=data(:,r);
        N_lam = length(lam);
        %%
        for j=1:N_lam
            kk=0;
            r1=0;
            if(sign(lam(j))==1)
                kk=kk+1;
                lampos(kk)=lam(j);
                if (length(lampos(kk))>3 &length(lamneg(r1))>2)
                 break
                end
            else
                r1=r1+1;
                lamneg(r1)=lam(j);
            end
        end
        cc{r}=[lampos lamneg];
    end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` function may be useful here, as it can help you to locate the locations where the function changes from positive to negative. The following locates the index `ind` of the last negative value of `data` (assumed here to be a 1D vector) before it rises above zero:

```
num_rises = 1;
ind = find(data(1:end-1)<=0 & data(2:end)>0, num_dips, 'first')
```

As such, for each column, you would be interested in the values of `ind-1,ind`, negative values, and `ind+1,ind+2` for the positive values.

It was also unclear to me how many sets of these 4 values were of interest to you. To find more regions where the data dips below the origin, change the value of `num_dips` to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks GJStein I tired what you wrote but I got empty array I have matrix with 25 row and 600 column but I could not to put all the data in the posting question

Comment: If you have an empty return from the `find` function, it indicates that your condition is not met. Is it possible that, for some of the columns, the data never crosses zero?

Comment: thanks, I want the output as array contains 4 point (2 negative 2 positive) For example for the first column I have

data(25,1)=[
  -0.0006662
  -0.00033225
  0.00033638
  0.001341
  0.0023478
  0.0057178
  0.012524
  0.022899
  0.033476
  0.070152
  0.15002
  0.28558
  0.43904
  1.0598
  2.6344
  5.3640
  8.2462
  18.1135
  38.0530
  68.0307
  98.0210
  198.0086
  397.9984
  698.0106
  998.0148]
I want the out put

transitions=[ -0.0006662 -0.00033225 0.00033638 0.001341]
I tried to use your code put I got empty array

Comment: I have updated this to work for a rise above zero now. In your question, I understood that you indicated that it was a fall you were looking for.