# How to apply a function on a subset of numpy.ndarray object

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy.ndarray` object of size `10000 x 20` and what I would like to do is simply to apply function `scipy.stats.mstats.zscore` on per row basis but without considering the non negative values. Any ideas?

```
# this works when considering all values
z_scores = st.mstats.zscore(data, axis=1, ddof=1)

# apparently, this does not work
z_scores = st.mstats.zscore(data[data>0], axis=1, ddof=1)
```

Comment: This may not be possible without looping, since the `data>0` mask is not shape-preserving in the sense that `data[data>0]` is 1D, as opposed to your 2D input, which is why the `axis=1` input results in an error.

Comment: Doesn't 'without considering non-negative values' mean considering only negative values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions in `scipy.stats.mstats` accept [*masked* arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html). Masked arrays allow
you to specify a mask (a boolean array) which tells the `mstats` function which
values to ignore.

So if you create a masked array which masks out the values you wish to ignore:

```
mask = data <= 0
mdata = np.ma.masked_array(data, mask)
```

then you can compute the desired values with:

```
zscores = mstats.zscore(mdata, axis=1, ddof=1)
```

For example,

```
import scipy.stats.mstats as mstats
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
data[data % 3 == 0] = -1
mask = data <= 0
mdata = np.ma.masked_array(data, mask)
zscores = mstats.zscore(mdata, axis=1, ddof=1)
print(zscores)
```

yields

```
[[-- -0.7071067811865475 0.7071067811865475 --]
 [-0.8728715609439694 -0.2182178902359922 -- 1.0910894511799623]
 [-1.0910894511799614 -- 0.21821789023599275 0.8728715609439699]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this calculation on the data directly seems impossible since the `data>0` mask is not shape-preserving in the sense that `data[data>0]` is 1D, as opposed to your 2D input, which is why the `axis=1` input results in an error.

The fastest way to accomplish this without using any loops may be to create a new data set with `np.nan` values for the `data<=0` entries and then to use the as in [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504491/how-can-i-sorting-the-values-in-the-jumping-columns/28506689?noredirect=1#comment45333309_28506689). The code would look like

```
masked_data = np.copy(data)
masked_data[masked_data>0] = np.nan

# Now use the nanmean and nanstd functions
z_score = x - scipy.stats.nanmean(masked_data)) / scipy.stats.nanstd(masked_data)
```

You will need to add the proper `axis` commands yourself, which I've omitted for clarity, but the idea is essentially the same. The `nanmean` and `nanstd` functions will ignore the `nan` values while preserving the shape of the array so that it can be properly vectorized.

Comment: thanks! so, what about this? `for d in data: print(st.mstats.zscore(d[d>0], ddof=1))` will it return the same results? how much slower will it be?

Comment: This will likely depend on your data, but my general rule is to err on the side of vectorized code (which scales better for larger sets), in case I want to use larger data sets later on. You're free to compare the two functions yourself for your particular data set and make the call then.

Comment: Though my answer will work, @unutbu's response (which I've just seen) is clearly the better solution. You should mark his as correct.